# ms access how to get first and last one in the same category

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access

I have a big table of car trips (trip name, cities that went through and entry and exit time. Table goes like this:

| id | city1 | time1 | city2 | time2 | city3 | time3 | city4 | time4 | city5 | time5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | bous | 11:00 | bouh | 11:10 | bir | 11:15 | chl | 11:30 | tns | 11:45 |
| 01 | fok | 00:00 | dwa | 00:10 | zer | 00:20 | CDP | 11:30 | CHRG | 11:35 |

And every city is from a state. I have a second table like this:

| city | state |
| --- | --- |
| bous | state1 |
| bouh | state1 |
| fok | state1 |
| dwa | state1 |
| bir | state1 |
| chl | state2 |
| tns | state2 |
| zer | state3 |
| CDP | state3 |
| CHRG | state3 |

What i want is to get the time of entry of each trip to a state and the exit time for example for trip 1:

| id | state | entry time | exit time | state | entry time | exit time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | state1 | 11:00 | 11:15 | state2 | 11:30 | 11:45 |

Comment: Access SQL provides the first and last aggregate functions to return the first and last values in a group.

Comment: @NicholasHunter care to explain more iam new to access and sql

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/miscellaneous/first-last-functions-microsoft-access-sql

Comment: @NicholasHunter well this function search vertically i want to search horizontally plus i wont to get all ghe states not only the first one

Comment: Data structure is not normalized. This will likely require a custom VBA function for horizontal search. Why is exit time not 11:45 for trip 1 and state 1? What state are fok and dwa in? Expand data sample and output example. You show time, but what about dates?

Comment: Is each record limited to a single state? Max 5 cities for each record? Multiple records for each state for each trip? Might be doable without VBA using UNION and aggregate queries.

Comment: @June7 fok and dwa are from state1 just forget to type em .i want to get every state in a trip and the entry time and exit time thats all m trying to do it with vba but no idea

Comment: No each trip can have up to 7 states and theres maximum of 15 cities

Comment: 15 city and time fields? Up to 7 records for each trip? Multiple dates? Where is date data? Is there a parent table with Trip info and the posted table 1 is a dependent table? Can trips cross days?

Comment: If fok and dwa are state 1 then answers question about whether a record is for a single state. Second record then has cities from 2 states. Really need to normalize this table.

Comment: @June7 so i fixed the tables check em now

Comment: Data still doesn't make sense. Think need dates with those times because otherwise 00:00 is the earliest time for trip 1 state 1.

Comment: @June7 it doesnt matter i think ... i just want to get every state in a trip and the entry,exit time of each state

Comment: It does matter when using aggregate queries. From your data, id 01 is trip 1, so trip 1 has two records. Both records will be considered when looking for first and last date/time values for each trip and state. Considering both records, it looks like itinerary was: State 1 > State 2 > State 1 > State3.

Comment: @June7 okey i can add the dates.... but how can i get the states and the entry exit time

Answer (score 1):

See if this gets you close to what you want. Table 1 must have a unique identifier field - autonumber should serve. Also, time fields are date/time type holding full date and time values.

Table1: TripDetails
Fields: ID_PK, TripID_FK, City1, Time1, etc

Query1: TripUNION
Start with a UNION query that rearranges data to more normalized structure.

```
SELECT ID_PK, TripID_FK, city1 AS City, time1 AS Tme FROM TripDetails
UNION SELECT ID_PK, TripID_FK, city2, time2 FROM TripDetails
UNION SELECT ID_PK, TripID_FK, city3, time3 FROM TripDetails
UNION SELECT ID_PK, TripID_FK, city4, time4 FROM TripDetails
UNION SELECT ID_PK, TripID_FK, city5, time5 FROM TripDetails
ORDER BY TripID_FK, Tme;
```

UNION is limited to 50 SELECT lines, so continue adding SELECT lines for the other city and time pairs. There is no designer for UNION - must type or copy/paste in SQLView.

Query2: join TripUNION query to Cities table for an aggregate query:

```
SELECT TripUNION.TripID_FK, TripUNION.ID_PK, Cities.state, 
       Min(TripUNION.Tme) AS Enter, Max(TripUNION.Tme) AS Exit
FROM TripUNION INNER JOIN Cities ON TripUNION.City = Cities.city
GROUP BY TripUNION.ID_PK, TripUNION.TripID_FK, Cities.state;
```

However, if there is a re-entry to a state on the same record, most likely the output will not be what is desired. Also, if a trip has multiple records involving only 1 state, likely output will again not be what is desired. Since your data did not show either case, this does produce desired output for given sample.